# Cross Domain Error in post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I am trying to write HTTP post request in AngularJS.

Sending POST request to `https://api.att.com/oauth/token`.

Following is the code snippet:

```
$scope.getToken = function () {
    /*alert('in get token');*/
    if($http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'https://api.att.com/oauth/token',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept':'application/json'
        },
        params: {
            'client_id':'myclientid',
            'client_secret':'mysecret',
            'grant_type':'client_credentials',
            'scope':'SPEECH'
        }
    }
```

Error in Chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.att.com/oauth/token?client_id=d3m1zlqukeyjctt5jj69jicwx4hxlpz9&…zzwjdrvf3cugiiaycxbujqkwjfze782&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=SPEECH. Origin http://localhost:8383 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Works fine with a temporary workaround: chrome.exe --disable-web-security .

Is there any other way in client side to solve this problem because I don't have any control on the server side?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: I hope you didn't just post your real login-credentials on an open webpage.

Comment: I edited your question to redact the credentials...review before posting!

Comment: The damage is already done. You should request new credentials.

Comment: Editing doesn't help. The full history of the post is visible. The credentials, if they were real, are compromised and should be changed.

Comment: It will all depend on what the api.att.com site allows. Your request is failing because your origin is not allowed to make that request. The fact that it works when you disable Chrome's web security indicates that Chrome is preflighting your request and the preflight is failing. Check your headers and make sure all are in accord with making a [simple cross origin request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests)